# EF6 update Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I'm trying to update many to many relationship using EF code first. Whenever I update I get this error, DietaryListings in the error is the join table created by migrations:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.DietaryListings'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DietaryListings'. The duplicate key value is (1, 52).
>   The statement has been terminated.

I realize that there is already existing duplicate data in DietaryListings before the update.  I just don't understand why EF isn't allowing the update using the mapped relationship between `Listing` and `Dietary`.  Shouldn't EF be updating the relationships if they change?  Do I need to manually delete duplicate records in that join table before doing an EF update to the entity?

In my MVC `Controller` I'm trying to update the existing object with the model data passed from a razor view using this:

```
//listing = updated model from razor view
//listingExisting = listing from db service 
foreach (var dietary in listing.Dietaries)
{
    if (dietary.Selected)
    {
        listingExisting.Dietaries.Add(dietary);
    }
}
listingExisting.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Modified;
_listingService.Update(listingExisting);
```

Listing class:

```
public partial class Listing : Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity
{
    public Listing()
    {   
        this.Dietaries = new List<Dietary>();  
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dietary> Dietaries { get; set; }
}
```

Dietaries class:

```
public partial class Dietary: Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity  
{
    public Dietary()        
    {            
        this.Listings = new List<Listing>();       
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }         
}
```

I've looked at all of these links and some where helpful but didn't work:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383494/mvc-4-many-to-many-relation-and-checkboxes) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157533/entity-framework-6-many-to-many-wants-to-insert-duplicate-rows) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926020/many-to-many-relationship-update-cannot-insert-duplicate-key) [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275699/entity-framework-updating-many-to-many-relationships-poco) [link5](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/686995/entity-framework-many-to-many-wants-to-insert-du) [link6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190985/primary-key-violation-on-adding-of-relationship-from-many-to-many-linked-tables)

Comment: If your idea is updating, why are you calling `listingExisting.Dietaries.Add(dietary);`? This is **adding** the object as if it was a new one, so EF is trying to insert a new one rather than updating. Also, if you want to update, what do you want to upadte, since `Dietary` class doesn't have any properties other than ID?

Comment: Do you have null property in listing.Dietaries ? If you want to update, should not be blank property in listing.Dietaries.Specially pk and fk objects.

Comment: @Alisson I'm updating the `Dietaries` that a `Listing` has.  So a `Listing` can have dietary1, dietary2...dietary10.  There are currently 10 `dietaries` in the database so any `Listing` can have any number of `dietaries` from 0..10.  I'm not updating any `dietary` entity, just the dietaries that a listing contains.  For simplicity, I took all the fields out of my classes since only the relationship was being updated.  I updated my question and added the name fields so they don't look like empty classes.